# Function returning data but object is undefined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have a function that returns the most recent submission into a collection that is delivering data to the console but the object remains undefined. I think my code is correct but I think it might be Iron Router catching something?

Template helper

```
Meteor.subscribe("date");

Template.reportsBeforeDelete.helpers({
  aboutToDelete: function() {
return Foods.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1});
  }
});
```

Publish

```
Meteor.publish('date', function(){
   return Foods.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1});
});
```

HTML template

```
<template name="reportsBeforeDelete">
    <div class="foods">
      {{aboutToDelete}}
    </div>
    {{debug aboutToDelete}}
</template>
```

Router

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('landing');
  } else {
    this.next();
 }
});

Router.configure ({
    layoutTemplate: 'home'
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'reports'});

Router.route('/activity'); 

Router.route('triggers');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the complete document as return value

> {{aboutToDelete}}

which attribute from the Foods collection should be rendered?...

Another solution would be to define this in the route itself:

```
Router.route('/foods/latest', {
  name: 'latestFoodsPage',
  data: function() { return Foods.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1});}

});
```

Comment: The text field and date field should be rendered from the Food collection, these are both displaying in the console.

How would the route work? My template is nested within another template to pull through the most recent submission into the home page

Comment: You have to use the #with helper: 
    {{#with aboutToDelete}}
       {{putYourDateFieldHere}} - {{putYourTextFieldHere}}
    {{/with aboutToDelete}}

Comment: Great to here that, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct so others see that there is a solution.

Comment: Although end of tag should be {{/with}} and sorting in route is useless, you should do It client side, and if you put limit on server there is no need to limit It on client since there is only one object available

Comment: @Sindis Thanks for the heads up. I will limit on the server.

Comment: Hi Dan, since there is not much value added for the community I didn't specify anything yet :) But I've added this to my SO profile now, thanks for pointing this out.